# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'voro'

Tags: python, python-3.x, ocr, tesseract

I am writing Python code to convert an image to text in Python on MacOS but run into this error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'voro'
```

This is the source code:

```
import pytesseract
import tesseract
```

I see this error after execution:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/spyder_kernels/py3compat.py:356 in compat_exec
    exec(code, globals, locals)

  File ~/Documents/tesseract_ocr.py:9
    import tesseract

  File ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tesseract/__init__.py:51
    import voro
```

I have also tried reinstalling tesseract on MacOS using brew but the error still shows up. What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I think tesseract is trying to import voro but you don't have it.
Try to install voro with

```
pip install voro
pip3 install voro
```

Comment: There is no module called `voro` in the PYPI.

Comment: I did try using your suggestion but it doesn’t work for me and is still giving error. It give the following error when using 'pip install voro': "ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement voro (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for voro" And when I use pip3 install voro this error comes: "Cell In[4], line 1
    pip3 install voro
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax"

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Why do you import [TesseRACt](https://pypi.org/project/tesseract/) package (compute concentrations of simulated dark matter halos from volume info for particles generated using Voronoi tesselation)?

Do not do that - IMO it is useless for you.

Answer (score 0):

You could try running
`pip install voro` or
`pip3 install voro`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).